# each loop on nested JSON children to build a course "chooser" using underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

Im trying to build a basic site fed with JSON That works as such…

[image: basic site organization]

So what I have setup is a table in mysql structured like so…

[image: basic sql table]

Where name is the initial list of buttons, then after choosing name you will get each successive choice as needed until you pull up the specific course detail.  hopefully I am strait forward so far.

### What I have tried so far (and it does work-ish).

so I use getJSON with a little bit of PHP like so...

```
    function getList() {
$.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getProducts.php', function(data) {
    products = data.items; });
```

then I do some $.each with some ifs and some appends...

```
    $.each(products, function(index, product) {
if (product.program === '' && product.platform === '') {
$('#theList').append('<div.....' + course etc.. + ');
};
if (product.program !== '' && product.platform === '') {
something else and so on....
```

and it works(mostly) but it completely sucks.  I have a version of the site right now, that I can click on the product and go through many of the options all the way to a course list and then course detail.  I end up having to do addition getJSON with url hashes to get the next level of choices and because I have wait for the data to load I have to create crazy id's for the divs to append to when the data is finally fetched so it appends in the correct place.  Like I said, it works, but I know it is the wrong way to do it. To be honest the mysql table is only 110 rows, i could have this all hardcoded a week or two faster than I am figuring this out.  But I really need to learn this.

### is underscore.js my solution?

so in my travels of the interwebs I discover underscore.js  and I try this..

```
    var Sample = _.groupBy(products, 'name');
console.log(Sample);
```

And I get a beautiful JSON array.

```
    {"Fred":[
{"name":"Fred","Type":"Red","program":"basic","platform":"windows"},
{"name":"Fred","Type":"Red","program":"basic","platform":"osx"},
{"name":"Fred","Type":"Red","program":"basic","platform":"OS X"},
{"name":"Fred","Type":"Red","program":"basic","platform":"osx"},
{"name":"Fred","Type":"Red","program":"basic","platform":"osx"},
{...
```

and if I do another groupBy on Sample.Fred for Type or program or platform, I get nice little arrays that have the exact data I need.  So now I have eliminate the need to do separate getJSON for each level, but I know there must be a better way to do this.  Is there a variable for the first level in objects?  sample.items doesn't get me anywhere and sample.objects doesn't either, sample.fred works, but then I am going to have to write out each name... sample.fred, sample.Jane, etc...  I know that isn't right either.

How do I say…

*for each object remove duplicate children (assuming I don't get the courses in my intial getJSON) and then append the values to sequentially nested divs???*

As it stands right now I will still have to do a ton of groupBy's and the $.each to append each option to the appropriate div.  but I have to believe there is a better and smarter way.

I hope this does't get nailed for being to localized, but I believe it is a basic concept and path I need to do here to be able to filter my way through children getting the list of values I need from particular items.

I realize there are many ways to do this with PHP and a ton of other ways I have never used though of or tried.  I don't really want to explore the PHP route as I want to expand my skills in javascript and jquery.

Thanks to any who are willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be better going with a full blown class and modeling the relationships. Then you can decide what owns what, and that will give you grouping as needed, as well as letting you easily add functionality and keep you from trying to manage a bunch of arrays.

Comment: Can you be  a bit more specific?  do you mean something like Ruby on Rails?  Sorry bit clueless.

Comment: Just read... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming.  It's a bit more than I wanted to dive into at the moment, but I'll keep reading, you could be right, I just have to get a grasp on it.  I was hoping to stay a bit closer than my comfort zone, but that may not be possible in this instance.

Comment: Here are some decent examples of how use classes in javascript. Admittedly javascript isn't really build for classes, but they often times become a practical requirement in more complex code. http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/